# Rails 4 Views - Best Practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two controllers, `UsersController` and `TransactionsController` and I'm wondering what the best practices is for displaying data from both controllers on one view. Should I create partials under each corresponding views directory and then stitch them together in a separate view or do I create one view under layouts? Am I way off?

**EDIT:**

In my Views folder:

- devise

  > (devise default views are in here)
- layouts

  > _header.html.erb
  >   application.html.erb
- transactions

  > _form.html.erb
  >   index.html.erb
  >   delete.html.erb
  >   edit.html.erb
  >   new.html.erb
- users

  > index.html.erb

I want to show both all users in one table and their transactions in another on the root page.

Comment: Could you provide an example on how data from one controller is related to the data from the other

Comment: 'User' has many transactions and 'Transaction' belongs to 'User'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show this data in an administration page for example then your code should go like this

```
Controllers:
admin_controller.rb -> with action users_transactions

views/admin
users_transactions.html.erb -> loop on users showing the partial of user

views/transcations
_user_transactions.html.erb

views/users
_user.html.erb -> here you will show how a single user will show including the partial of his transactions.
```

Answer (score 0):

If transactions belong to user, you should be able to access transaction data on the user page by default (if models&migrations are set up correctly). If your users index.html.erb will be your root page, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess it all depends on 'what' you want to display and 'how'.

Leave the views/layouts Dir for what it was created, storing layouts. Generally cross-view partials are kept in the views/shared Dir, which stores partials that could be rendered from another directories. in your case form transactions/* & users/*.

Plan wisely before adding a file there... maybe you don't really need it ;)